# `arguments` Cannot get the default value of the `Destructuring` parameter?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
const supersearch = function({a = 1, b}) {
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  console.log(a, b);
};

supersearch({b: 2});
```

expected outcome:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}

1 2
```

but actual results:

```
{
  "b": 2
}

1 2
```

How should i get `arguments` ?

doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

---

update:

A way I can think of now, is there a better way to write it?

```js
const supersearch = function({a, b}) {
  console.log({...{a: 1}, ...arguments[0]});
  console.log(a, b);
};

supersearch({b: 2});
```

Comment: Don't use `arguments`. If you need the entire object in a variable, do it on the first line of the function instead

Comment: I have a lot of parameters, and I am not sure if it is empty, I need to take out all the parameters that are not empty

Comment: @ebyteebyte It's not clear what you want to achieve. Maybe rest operator `...` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Alireza Yes, the second piece of code above achieves what I want, but I don't know if there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

hi you define one one argument of object type so that is happning

```js
const supersearch = function({}) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(arguments[0]));
  alert(arguments[0].a + '' + arguments[0].b);
};

supersearch({a:1 ,b: 2});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```js
  const supersearch = function({a = 1, b, ...rest}) {
  console.log({a,b});
  console.log(a, b);
};

supersearch({b: 2});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
 const supersearch = function(inputParams) {
          const defaulParams = { a: 1};
          const allParams = {...defaultParams, ...inputParams}; 
          const {a,b} = allParams;
          console.log(allParams);
          console.log(a, b);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign({a: 1}, args);` like below. And `destruct` object inside `function` instead of in `parameter`.

```js
const supersearch = function(args) {  
  let {a, b} = Object.assign({a: 1}, args);
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  console.log(a, b);
};

supersearch({b: 2});
supersearch({a: 10, b: 2});
```